# Optaplanner doesn't see my planning variable

Tags: optaplanner

So I have a class Cycle:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Cycle {
  private Integer START = 29;
  private Integer END = 42;
  private final int SUSTAIN_START = 29;
  private final int SUSTAIN_END = 72;

  @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "startRange" } )
  public Integer getStartIndex() {
    System.out.println("DEBUG: getStartIndex");
    return START;

  }

  public void setStartIndex(Integer i) {
    System.out.println("DEBUG: setStartIndex");
    START = i;
    END = i+13;
  }

  @ValueRangeProvider(id = "startRange")
  public List<Integer> getStartIndexes () {
    ArrayList<Integer> startRange = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = SUSTAIN_START; i < SUSTAIN_END; i++) {
      startRange.add(i);
    }
    return startRange;
  }

}
```

and Optplanner doesn't ever call any of these methods, and I have no clue why. I've tried adding a "@ProblemFactCollectionProperty" annotatation on the getStartIndexes method, but I read in the docs that that annotation should only be used within a PlanningSolution.

I've also tried using scanAnnotatedClasses and explicitly specifying the entityClass in my solver config and neither seemed to make a difference.

Why can't Optaplanner see my variable and why doesn't Optaplanner change it?

More Info: I'm using Optaplanner version 7.30.0.Final and I have another planning entity with two planning variables that are seen and changed by Optaplanner.

Comment: Your planning entity looks OK. The problem might be in your solver config or in the planning solution. Make sure that in your solver config XML you're using either `<scanAnnotatedClasses/>` or have an `<entityClass>` element for each entity. In the solution class, you should have two `@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty` annotated methods, one returning a collection of `Cycle`s, one returning a collection of the other type of entities. If none of that helps please share more code (solver config, solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, per @yurloc's comment, was that I was missing the PlanningEntityCollectionProperty for Cycles in my PlanningSolution class. Thanks for the help!